# Calling notifyListeners() causes errors when called in deactivate() - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I have read all the questions related to this issue, but neither of them is similar to mine.

I have two pages: homepage and settings page. In the homepage, I listen to changes of provider with `Consumer`. In the settings page, I don't listen to changes:

```dart
class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
    StatesProvider states;

    @override
    void initState() {
        states =  Provider.of<StatesProvider>(context, listen: false);
        super.initState();
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return myUi();
    }
     

    @override
    void deactivate() {
        states.changeSettings(settings); //just a dummy function, doesn't do anything  
        states.finishSetting();
        super.deactivate();
    }

}
```

I have cut out unnecessary codes. What I am trying to do in code above is changing some app settings and applying them when I leave that settings page.

`finishSetting()` method:

```dart
finishSetting() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for StatesProvider:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I know that `notifyListeners()` calls `build()` method of Widgets listening to it. But when I leave the settings page, I don't see any widget's `build()` method called. What should I do?

Generally, is there a way to call `notifyListeners()` when I leave page?

Answer (score 1):

This could be that you are overwriting the wrong function:

- deactivate is called when the widget gets temporarily deactivated
- Try using ["dispose, which is called after deactivate if the widget is removed from the tree permanently"](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/deactivate.html)

In general I would advise you to have a look at navigation, maybe a simple ["onPopPage"](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/onPopPage.html) at the place where you are routing to your page could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, `dispose()` gives the same error and I don't know how to implement `onPopPage`

Comment: I analyzed navigation and saw that I gotta change a lot more things to get it work. It works now and without you, it wouldn't have been possible. I will award bounty to you, but won't accept answer, because it really didn't answer my question. I hope you understand.